# Where is my Django installation?

Tags: python, django, path, installation

I use Django but I need to find the default templates and applications.

I don't know where it's installed.

How can I find that?

Comment: What platform you running on? Ubuntu? Mac? what...

Answer (score 170, accepted):

in the CLI you can do this:

```
>>> import django
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

Answer (score 30):

```
$ python
>>> import django
>>> django.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'
```

Answer (score 14):

The current top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7037502/466771) doesn't work, at least on linux.

From the Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel):

> If you have difficulty finding where the Django source files are
>   located on your system, run the following command:

```
python -c "
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import django
print(django.__path__)"
```

Comment: Current top (accepted) answer works with my Ubuntu installation. 
As does yours. As do all of them!

Comment: @olafure sys.path assignment not required. Nonetheless, your code is right!

Comment: a practical approach to the python -c command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/

Answer (score 13):

On Microsft-Windows OS: In the **Lib/site-packages** folder inside your python installation.

Answer (score 7):

As the comments on @olafure's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12974642/4515198 rightly say, the `sys.path` assignment is not required.

The following will be enough:

```sh
python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
```

Here the `-c` option is used to tell python that a "program is being passed in as string" (source: command `$ python --help` on `bash`)

Answer (score 4):

This approach I am describing works across operating systems...

You try this on your command line - `python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"`

This gives you the base directory. From there, type `/django/` and here you find all the default templates, admin templates, etc.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

```
import django
django.__file__
```

output will be given location of the django folder

```
'C:\\Users\\saigopi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py'
```

Comment: That is my response years ago (the first one actually) but SO's algo decides to put it in the last position...

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that if you are using a virtual env all the packages will be in your project's root venv folder under "lib" ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this on an terminal.

```
$ python -v
import django # directory /home/user/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
# some other imports.
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was running the below command in terminal

`pip show django`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using virtualenv then it will be:
 /home/user/path where you installed django/django_directory/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html
 **base-site.html** is the default template.